# How to use JSON AUTO in sql server to get required format?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am trying to use JSON AUTO in Stored Procedure, but looks like OFFSET-FETCH kind of not giving expected format while I get the expected format when execute in a SELECT statement like this:

```
  Select
    p.PaymentId,
    c.ClaimID,
    c.Value
    from Payment p inner join Claims c
    on p.Pid = c.Pid
    FOR JSON AUTO
```

The expected output is where claim is shown as a child of payment:

```json
[
    {
        "PaymentId": 1041628747792385062,
        "c": [
            {
                "ClaimID": 1041628747792385063,
                "Value": 3.00
            },
            {
                "ClaimID": 1041628747792385066,
                "Value": 0.10
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "PaymentId": 1041631356649473081,
        "c": [
            {
                "ClaimID": 1041631356649473082,
                "Value": 3.00
            },
            {
                "ClaimID": 1041631356649473085,
                "Value": 0.10
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "PaymentId": 1041631977406465100,
        "c": [
            {
                "ClaimID": 1041631977406465101,
                "Value": 3.00
            },
            {
                "ClaimID": 1041631977406465104,
                "Value": 0.10
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "PaymentId": 1041632170344449119,
        "c": [
            {
                "ClaimID": 1041632170344449120,
                "Value": 3.00
            },
            {
                "ClaimID": 1041632170344449123,
                "Value": 0.10
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "PaymentId": 1041633764179969138,
        "c": [
            {
                "ClaimID": 1041633764179969139,
                "Value": 3.00
            },
            {
                "ClaimID": 1041633764179969142,
                "Value": 0.10
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "PaymentId": 1042148522721281535,
        "c": [
            {
                "ClaimID": 1042148531109889536,
                "Value": 3.00
            },
            {
                "ClaimID": 1042148531109889539,
                "Value": 0.10
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When I execute it in a Stored Procedure like below, the hierarchy is not maintained.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPayment]
@PId BIGINT,
@PageNumber INT = 1,
@PageSize INT = 10,
@IsSummary BIT = 0

AS
BEGIN



SELECT
P.[PaymentId] as 'PaymentId',
C.[ClaimId] as 'ClaimId',
C.[Value] as 'Value'
INTO #Payments 
FROM
Payments P  INNER JOIN Claims c ON P.IdPayment = c.IdPayment



IF @IsSummary = 1 
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #Payments
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM
    #Payments p
    ORDER BY PaymentId
    OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
    FOR JSON AUTO
END
END
```

**The output:**

```json
[
    {
        "PayoutId": 1041628747792385062,
        "ClaimId": 1041628747792385063,
        "Value": 3.00
    },
    {
        "PayoutId": 1041628747792385062,
        "ClaimId": 1041628747792385066,
        "Value": 0.10
    },
    {
        "PayoutId": 1041631356649473081,
        "ClaimId": 1041631356649473082,
        "Value": 3.00
    },
    {
        "PayoutId": 1041631356649473081,
        "ClaimId": 1041631356649473085,
        "Value": 0.10
    },
    {
        "PayoutId": 1041631977406465100,
        "ClaimId": 1041631977406465101,
        "Value": 3.00
    },
    {
        "PayoutId": 1041631977406465100,
        "ClaimId": 1041631977406465104,
        "Value": 0.10
    },
    {
        "PayoutId": 1041632170344449119,
        "ClaimId": 1041632170344449120,
        "Value": 3.00
    },
    {
        "PayoutId": 1041632170344449119,
        "ClaimId": 1041632170344449123,
        "Value": 0.10
    },
    {
        "PayoutId": 1041633764179969138,
        "ClaimId": 1041633764179969139,
        "Value": 3.00
    },
    {
        "PayoutId": 1041633764179969138,
        "ClaimId": 1041633764179969142,
        "Value": 0.10
    }
]
```

Comment: please makea complete [mre]

Comment: Why are you doing the insert to a temp table step?

Comment: Don't use JSON Auto, build your json by subquerying the Claims table

Comment: You're explicitly asking for a flat format. [Check the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-json-output-automatically-with-auto-mode-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16), they show that the actual format depends on the column aliases. Naming a column `'Info.MiddleName'` will emit an `Info` object with a `MiddleName` attribute

Comment: Not to mention that the temporary table makes it *impossible* for the data to be anything other than one object per row.

Comment: Also, as a side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).